# JavaScript não esta a comunicar com o html

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Então eu estou a fazer um alicativo de pc com o `electron` que use `html, js e css` mas quando eu estava  a tentar que um valor no html se alterace com o meu js ele não fazia nada mas quando eu colocava o script dentro do html ja funcionava, problema é que eu precisava de ter um ficheiro js so para fazer essas mudanças!.

**Meu HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EComerce App Slime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="UpperBar">
      <p class="MASlime">MASlime</p>
      <p class="Home">HOME</p>
    </div>
    <div id="HomePage">
      <div id="Totals">
        <p class="TotalEarnings">Total Earnings</p>
        <p class="TotalOrders">Total Orders</p>
        <p id="Earnings">HIII</p>
      </div>
      <div id="NewOrder">

      </div>
      <div id="Recipe">
        <div id="Small">

        </div>
        <div id="Medium">

        </div>
        <div id="Big">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MEU JS**

```
var element = document.getElementById("Earnings");
element.innerHTML = "100€";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está inserindo o seu `<script>` dentro do `<head>`. 
Tente declarar o seu `<script>` antes do final da tag `<body>` conforme abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EComerce App Slime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="UpperBar">
      <p class="MASlime">MASlime</p>
      <p class="Home">HOME</p>
    </div>
    <div id="HomePage">
      <div id="Totals">
        <p class="TotalEarnings">Total Earnings</p>
        <p class="TotalOrders">Total Orders</p>
        <p id="Earnings">HIII</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 
     ####################
     OS ARQUIVOS DE SCRIPTS VEM AQUI 
     ####################
    -->
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

E então faça a inserção da sua função **JS** no arquivo separado `index.js`

Espero ter ajudado.
Se resolveu, contribua marcando como resposta correta. Caso não funcione, detalhe mais algumas opções de informação, por exemplo: **o que mostra o console de desenvolvedor do navegador**

Sucesso mano!

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou direitinho! Depois de muita pesquisa a unica coisa que precisava er de vir ao stackoverflow!